# Meson custom_target never executes despite sources and dependencies out of date

Tags: ninja, meson-build

I've got this section in my project's root's `meson.build`:

```
if get_option('gen_py_bindings')

  message('told to build py bindings')

  custom_target('py_bindings', 
command: ['env', '_MESON_MODULE_NAME=' + meson.project_name(), ',_MESON_MODULE_VERSION=' + meson.project_version(), './py3_bindings/setup.py', 'build'], 
depends: [mainlib], 
depend_files: files(['py3_bindings/module.c', 'py3_bindings/setup.py']), 
input: ['py3_bindings/setup.py'], 
install: false, output: 'sharedextension.so')

endif
```

It's a custom target that runs a `setup.py` script to build python bindings for my project's library.

---

The problem is that it is always seemingly up-to-date. I've used the `depends` keyword argument to specify that it depends on another build target in the project, and the `depend_files` keyword argument to specify that it depends on the C source file that the script uses to build the extension, as well the actual script that is being ran as the `command`. I've also used the `input` keyword argument even though I don't understand the difference between it and `depend_files`.

---

I can only get the custom target to regenerate if I make a change to `meson.build` (the `message()` call is displayed successfully).

No other change will do. I've tried updating all files listed in the custom target but it always results in: `ninja: no work to do.`. Even if other out-of-date targets get rebuilt/relinked/etc...

I'm using `ninja 1.9.0` and `meson 0.52.1` on linux.

---

I am also well aware of the `build_always_stale` keyword argument but I don't want to use it unless necessary. (update: setting it to `true` still doesn't result in the target rebuilding, looks like there's something more at play here but I can't figure it out).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, custom targets don't get built when running plain `ninja` and thus the `build_by_default` keyword argument needs to be passed and set to `true`, e.g.

```
custom_target('target', build_by_default: true)
```